# Creating minipage of required height

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm failing to understand how to properly create a minipage of a required height:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c][4.5cm][c]{0.48\textwidth}
        \frame{
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \foreach \i in {-10, -9, ..., 0}
                {
                    \node at (0, \i) {$\i$};
                }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        }
    \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Apparently this creates a two page high minipage. Why?

Comment: it would be a lot easier for people to debug, and test answers, if your code was in th eform of a test document. You said the content was not relevant so you should be able to make a complete document, but replacing `\import{./}{File.E}` by `ZZZ`  or whatever example text shows the problem.

Comment: that said the `\centering` here can do nothing `\centering
    \frame{
    \resizebox{\textwidth}`   as the inner box is already textwidth wide then you have a space to the left of it (from the space after `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, reworked the question. I think I have a basic misunderstanding with the functionality of height parameter of minipage

Comment: If you put an `\fbox` around the minipage, you will discover that LaTeX **thinks** it is still the size you specified.  The actual contents are spilling out all over the page, though.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The vertical size option to `minipage` works like the horizontal size option to `\makebox`  It sets the external dimensions of the box but allows any over-sized content to silently overflow. as you have the `[c]` option it overflows equally at top and bottom.

So your minipage is the size indicated in red here, but teh content is bigger than the page as you have scaled it to be that large.

I have added an `\fbox` around the minipage so its external dimensions are clear for debugging.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][4.5cm][c]{0.48\textwidth}
        \frame{
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \foreach \i in {-10, -9, ..., 0}
                {
                    \node at (0, \i) {$\i$};
                }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        }
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

Note `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` should be `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%`  otherwise your force white space to the left (and similarly avoid spaces at the end) but it isn't clear if you want `\resizebox` at all here.